# POST request with Ruby and Calabash

Tags: ruby, post

I use Calabsh to test iOS app. Duringtest I need to create POST request to change some values and then verify that changes are reflected in UI.

Request looks like:

wwww.testserver.com/userAddMoney?user_id=1&amount=999

To authorize on server I need to pass special parameters to Header of request:

Headers: X-Testing-Auth-Secret: kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.testserver.com/userAddMoney?user_id=1&amount=999')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
##  https.use_ssl = true    # use https, need require net/https
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req['X-Testing-Auth-Secret'] = 'kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76'
res = http.request(req)
```

Docs here: [Net::HTTP::Post](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Post.html)  [Net::HTTPSession](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)